# Why I should include CommonModule in child modules?

Tags: angular

Why I should include CommonModule in child modules if this module already was included in main module `AppModule`?

```
AppModule(Root) -> includes -> CommonModule
CustomModule -> incudes -> CommonModule
AppModule -> incudes -> CustomModule>
```

I think `CommonModule` is redundant in `CustomModule`, because it is globally declarated in `CommonModule`? isn't it ?

Comment: Check out this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slyrn1). Try removing `CommonModule` from `imports` of `HelloModule`. `HelloComponent` is using `*ngIf`, without that import, even though it's parent module `AppModule` imports `CommonModule`, it will error without the import.

Comment: Why in this example there is not export `CommonModule` in appModule to make this global?

Comment: Why would it be exported from `AppModule`? Feature/Child modules would never import `AppModule` by any standard convention.

Comment: But `Feature/Child modules` always are imported in `AppModule` is not?

Comment: They may be imported into `AppModule`, but not the other way around. Adding `CommonModule` to the `exports` of `AppModule` doesn't expose that to feature/child modules. Try it in the example, `HelloComponent` will error, even if you export `CommonModule` from `AppModule`.

Comment: Why not CommonModule to the exports doesn't expose that to feature/child modules? If it was set in appModue in export directive?

Comment: No, exporting `CommonModule` from `AppModule`, does not it expose to child/feature modules. Try it in the example.

Comment: I got you, but I dont understand why?

Comment: I won't even pretend to understand the **complete** inner workings of `NgModule`. If you really need to know why feature/child modules do not automatically consume imported/exported modules of a parent `NgModule` you would probably need to go through the source code and step through compiled/generated code of your application. Sorry, I wish I could explain it in technical detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because if you want to use any of the exported features(Component, Directive, Pipe) of the [`CommonModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) in your `CustomModule`, you can't do that without adding the `CommonModule` to the `imports` array of the `CustomModule`.

If you imported the `CommonModule` in your `AppModule`, you'll **only** be able to use the exported members of `CommonModule` in the registered(added to the `declarations`) Components, Directives, Pipes etc of the `AppModule`. If you export the `CommonModule` from the `AppModule`, since `AppModule` is your Root Module and you will not add it to the `imports` array of any other module, you won't be able to use the exported members of the `CommonModule` anywhere else, unless imported there as well.

You can use services from CommonModule(although it's not recommended) in the CustomModule(if `providedIn: 'root'`) since they are registered on the Root Injector. But apart from that, nothing else would be usable unless its imported.

#### Why providing services from `CommonModule`(or `SharedModule` whatever you want to call it) is not recommended?

From [**Angular Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-10):

> Consider not providing services in shared modules. Services are usually singletons that are provided once for the entire application or in a particular feature module. There are exceptions, however. For example, in the sample code that follows, notice that the SharedModule provides FilterTextService. This is acceptable here because the service is stateless;that is, the consumers of the service aren't impacted by new instances.

Comment: So, if I imported custom package (dependency) in appModule. Does it mean, that all component in system(any nested component) are available to use this, or I should add this dependency also in export appModule?

Comment: @Marshal, I've updated the answer to address your question.

Comment: @OPV, not that's not how it works. If something is exported from a module, the module that will import it only will have access to this something. But since you won't export anything from the `AppModule` since it is the `RootModule`, you won't have access to the exported members of the `CommonModule` anywhere else.